# JS - Input type="date" doesn't recognized oninput/onchange

Tags: javascript, html, input

I'm currently working on a dynamic form, which calculates the duration between two dates. However, my input-field doesn't recognize, if the input ends with 0. Here's the code

HTML:

```
<input type="time" value="" step="2" onchange="UpdateEndingTime(this.value)">
```

JS:

```
function UpdateEndingTime(pEndingTime){
 console.log(pEndingTime)
}
```

What causes this problem? What is a possible workaround?

Thanks in advance

**EDIT**

Ok, I don't exactly know, why oninput does not work, but I found a workaround with `onkeydown`, which basically does what I want.

Thanks @MarcReed and everyone for making that idea appear in my head.

Comment: what do you mean by ending with zero ?

Comment: From what  I can tell in this snippet, is that you have `step="2"`. That's just going to step over everything that's not an interval of 2, so if the date starts at 1, the only valid values will be 1,3,5,7,9,11,13...etc. If you change step to 1, then you should be able to select any date.

Comment: @BILAL For example: The user can enter the string "12:00:00" to indicate, that the event will end 12am, but the event only triggers after "12:00" but not at "12:00:00"

Comment: @King11 Sorry, I just tried it, it didn't work

Comment: @LennyWill Are you talking about dates or times? I'm not fully understanding your question based off the the code snippet you shared and your previous comment

Comment: @King11Thanks for making me aware of this, I provided the wrong type. It should be "time". I corrected that

Comment: Exactly what problem are you seeing? You know that `onchange` won't trigger until focus moves out of the field, right?

Comment: @LennyWill ok, so your only issue is its not displaying the last `00` when the input ends in "00" correct? Also why are you using `step = 2` for this?

Comment: @MarkReed No, I didn't know that, but it doesn't work with oninput either. I want to trigger the event every time the user makes an input

Comment: @King11 No, my problem is, that when the user enters 00 at the end of the string, the trigger is not fired

Comment: Maybe what you want is an `onkeypress` event instead of an `onchange` event.